# Simple Weight Question

Tags: weights

This is a very basic question regarding weights.

Let us say I have product A that has 100 reviews. Let us say 80 of these reviews are positive and 20 of these reviews are negative. The score for product A is 80%.

Let us say I have product B that has 1000 reviews. Let us say 800 of these reviews are positive and 200 of these reviews are negative. The score for product B is 80%.

Even though the scores for product A and B are equal, I think that the score for Product B should be higher because more people filled out feedback then they did for Product A.

What is the best way to account for the weight of the sample size in a formula that yields a percentage score?

Comment: The increase in sample size means that the variance of the estimate is smaller for product B.  There is no better estimate but the variance is reduced by a factor of ten meaning that the standard deviation is reduce by a factor of the square root of 10.

Answer (score 1):

You have a series of [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) trials and you're estimating the parameter $p$ of a good review.

(+1) @Michael Chernick expresses the most firmly grounded, classic statistical way to think about it.

#### An alternative, Bayesian approach:

An alternative is to become a [Bayesian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability), and instead of treating $\rho$ as a parameter (i.e. some number), you can model $\rho$ as a [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable)! That is, you can use the tools of probability to model the uncertainty in your head about $\rho$. You will:

- Start with some beliefs about $\rho$ (this is your "prior")
- Update those beliefs based upon whether review $1$ is positive or negative. (This is called forming the "posterior.")
- Repeat, do the same thing with review $2$, review $3$, etc....

If we represent our beliefs about $\rho$ using the beta distribution, then our beliefs about $\rho$ after observing a new review will also follow the beta distribution because it is a [conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions) when the likelihood is Bernoulli.

You can then compute the maximum the [maximum a posteriori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) estimate.

Anyway, the way this work out in simplest terms is before see any *actual* reviews, you initialize your beliefs about $\rho$ **as if** there were $\alpha$ positive reviews and $\beta$ negative reviews. Let's say you then observe $x$ *actual* positive reviews and $y$ *actual* negative reviews. You would act as if you've seen $\alpha + x$ positive reviews. Your maximum a posteri estimate would be:

$$\hat{p} = \frac{\alpha + x}{\alpha + x + \beta + y}$$

And your posterior (over $\rho$) follows the [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with parameters $\alpha + x$ and $\beta + y$.

You're effectively incorporating some initial beliefs about whether the product is good or bad.

The **weakness** of this approach is that your choices of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ may be difficult to justify! Should it be $\alpha =1$ and $\beta=1$? $\alpha = 4.2$ and $\beta = 2.1$? If you have some objective way to set $\alpha$ and $\beta$ based upon outside data, outside information, then the Bayesian approach makes more sense. If you're pulling your choices for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ out of a magic hat, then it can be rather arbitrary.